# How can I find the relationship between a categorical variable (zip codes) and the number of occurrence of another variable?

Tags: python, data-analysis, correlation, categorical-data, frequency-distribution

I have the following data frames: and I want to find the **correlation** between zip codes and number of violations per zip code. What is best way to calculate/quantify the relationship in Python?

```
    VIOLATION CODE  Zip Codes
0                F049    25426.0
1                F042    25426.0
2                F037    25426.0
3                F015    25426.0
4                F006    25426.0
```

[Data frame sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/834de.png)

[The data types of the variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFwzj.png)

Comment: Are you just trying to count the number of violations per zip code? Could you do a groupby?

Comment: Yes, but I want to quantitative the relationship, how could I do that?